# need advice on speeding up query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This query takes about 9 seconds and returns 2 records.

```
SELECT

s.description, s.improvement,
s.first_name, s.last_name, s.finding, s.action, s.share, 
s.learned, s.timestamp, d.title as department_title, 
group_concat(DISTINCT g.title SEPARATOR " | ") as strategic_goals,
group_concat(DISTINCT m.statement SEPARATOR " | ") as mission_references,
group_concat(DISTINCT meas.statement SEPARATOR " | ") as measure_statement,
group_concat(DISTINCT o.statement SEPARATOR " | ") as outcome_statement,
group_concat(DISTINCT i.title SEPARATOR " | ") as ilo_title,
group_concat(DISTINCT cv.title SEPARATOR " | ") as core_value_title,
y1.year as current_year_title, y2.year as previous_year_title,
u.file_name as file_name

FROM summary s

LEFT JOIN year y1 ON s.current_year_id = y1.id
INNER JOIN year y2 ON s.previous_year_id = y2.id

INNER JOIN strategic_goal_entries sge ON s.id = sge.summary_id
INNER JOIN goal g ON sge.goal_id = g.id

INNER JOIN outcome o ON s.id = o.summary_id
LEFT JOIN measure meas ON o.id = meas.outcome_id

INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN uploads u ON s.id = u.summary_id 

INNER JOIN mission_entries me ON s.id = me.summary_id
LEFT JOIN mission m ON me.mission_id = m.id

LEFT JOIN ilo_entries ie ON s.id = ie.summary_id
LEFT JOIN ilo i ON ie.ilo_id = i.id

INNER JOIN core_value_entries cve ON s.id = cve.summary_id
INNER JOIN core_value cv ON cve.core_value_id = cv.id

INNER JOIN executive_of_department eod ON s.department_id = eod.department_id

WHERE eod.executive_id = 3

GROUP BY s.id
```

I added the rest of the primary keys. Query went from 9 seconds to 2 seconds.

Then I set fields that refer to other table's primary keys, as index fields. The query went from 2 seconds to 20 seconds, did I assign too many indexes?

What are some ways I could speed this up?

Comment: What is the indexing situation? Tuning the indexes would be my first option.

Comment: +1 John - Indexes  are the first suspect, esp. with so many `JOIN`s.

Comment: Also @Brad, you may get unexpected results since you have aggregate functions on some fields, and group by a single field that's not even in the select list...

Comment: Ensure DISTINCT is necessary.

Comment: Added primary keys to the tables that did not have them. Went from 12 seconds to 2 seconds. I have tables that keep track of what departments an executive oversees (executive_of_department), which contains two fields: executive_id and department_id, tables like those...do they need a primary key set? if so, what one in this case?

Comment: @JohnFx: I have not set any indexes. Should I set indexes on fields like: s.department_id, eod.executive_id, eod.department_id, me.mission_id, me.summary_id, o.summary_id, meas.outcome_id, u.summary_id, etc...

Comment: Set all s.department_id, s.previous_year_id, s.current_year_id, o.summary_id, meas.outcome_id, ie.ilo_id, i.id, ie.summary_id as indexes, now my 2 second query turned into a 20 second query. What may of happened? Maybe I went index happy.

Comment: If you have no indexes with this query performance will suck. I'd make sure you have an index at least on every column that is involved in a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** After setting indexes, etc. you can speed up a little by limiting the `JOIN` conditions. For example, instead of

```
LEFT JOIN uploads u ON s.id = u.summary_i
```

do

```
LEFT JOIN uploads u ON (s.id = u.summary_i AND s.id = 3)
```

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated *after* all tables have been joined. Preciese your `JOIN` condition when you can.

---

**2.** Did you try constructing a view from your select and perform a `SELECT * FROM myView WHERE myView.id = 3` ?

**UPDATE :** read [this blog comment](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/#comment-897).

Comment: But but views are not indexed so won't the view make stuff slower?

Comment: @Johan, if there are many data updates, yes. However I don't know the uses cases involving the question, so this is why I said "did you try..."

Comment: Oh does the output of a View get cached somewhere? I did not know that.